# How do I display categories assigned to entry within Channel entries tag

Tags: categories

In my code below I'm trying to list the category_url_titles within data-type. This is returning all the categories for that channel, but I only want to show the categories assigned to that entry. I thought maybe there would be an entry_id="{entry_id}" thing for the channel categories tag, but there isn't. Any ideas?

```
    {exp:channel:entries channel="locations" dynamic="no"}
    <a href="{title_permalink=locations/details/}" data-type="{exp:channel:categories style="linear" }{category_url_title} {/exp:channel:categories}"></a>
    {/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Within your `channel:entries` loop, use the [categories loop](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#categories):

```
data-type="{categories backspace="1"}{category_url_title} {/categories}"
```

Comment: Wow, I've been scanning the EE docs for a while and must have kept skipping that. Thanks!